# Plotting the images of complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am new  to complex analysis and its pretty hard for me to visualize complex functions. In particular I was trying to visualize the branches of the Lambert W function from complex $z$ plane to $w$ plane where $W(z)e^{W(z)}=z$. I want to plot the images of $z=(-\infty,-1/e]$, $z=[-1/e,0)$, for positive real axis and imaginary axis. We can take $z=x+iy$ and $w=\xi+i\eta$. I don't know how to obtain these plots or from where do I start? Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for general ways to visualize complex functions, I put together this Python code to create plots that color by phase and show the magnitude as contours: [github.com/seaplant3/complex-plotting](https://github.com/seaplant3/complex-plotting).

It would be hard to use this for the Lambert W function since it is hard to write in a concise form, but [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) gives some plots and forms you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer to the question, but with [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot) you can visualize at least one branch of the Lambert W function. It uses [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) with some contours.

```
import cplot
from scipy.special import lambertw

plt = cplot.plot(lambertw, (-2.0, +2.0, 400), (-2.0, +2.0, 400))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note the branch cut emanating from $-1/e$.